# What is the difference between forEach and forEachEntry in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, java-8

In Java 8 `ConcurrentHashMap` had two new methods introduced viz. [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#forEach-long-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and [`forEachEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#forEachEntry-long-java.util.function.Consumer-).

On closer look both of them have essentially same arguments - `forEach` has key & value supplied via `BiConsumer` while `forEachEntry` has `Map.Entry` supplied via `Consumer` from where key & value can be derived.

A simple use case to print all the map entries can be implemented by either of them as below

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = Stream.of("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five").
            collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap( str -> str, 
                                                str -> str.length(), 
                                                (str, len) -> len, 
                                                ConcurrentHashMap::new));

map.forEach(1, (k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));

map.forEachEntry(1, entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()));
```

Moreover from docs the `Map.Entry.setValue` isn't supported for bulk operation; so the benefit of having the `Map.Entry` over plain key-value seems defeated.

> .... that may transiently change while computation is in progress; and except for forEach actions, should ideally be side-effect-free. Bulk operations on `Map.Entry` objects do **not** support method `setValue`.

Thus IMO two methods can be used interchangeably (*unless I miss something very obvious*)

So my questions are

- Why two methods with essentially same signature were introduced
- If there are any differences what are they
- What benefit does one method have over another (*a simple use case explaining them would suffice*)

Comment: There is `forEach`, `forEachKey`, `forEachValue`. I think it is just for completeness to introduce a `forEachEntry` method.

Comment: @Flown I wonder what my review team would say if I'll do the same thing... introduce a new method that does close to the same thing... I wonder if that is the real reason, then why not just deprecate `forEach`?

Comment: @Eugene Maybe there are already methods which are using `Map.Entry` as parameter. Then you have to wrap the key-values again in `Map.Entry` objects. This is what I've meant by saying for completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only difference is that one accepts a BiConsumer and the other just a Consumer.

Here the relevant code:

```
// forEach
static final class ForEachMappingTask<K,V>
    extends BulkTask<K,V,Void> {
    final BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action;
    ForEachMappingTask
        (BulkTask<K,V,?> p, int b, int i, int f, Node<K,V>[] t,
         BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action) {
        super(p, b, i, f, t);
        this.action = action;
    }
    public final void compute() {
        final BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action;
        if ((action = this.action) != null) {
            for (int i = baseIndex, f, h; batch > 0 &&
                     (h = ((f = baseLimit) + i) >>> 1) > i;) {
                addToPendingCount(1);
                new ForEachMappingTask<K,V>
                    (this, batch >>>= 1, baseLimit = h, f, tab,
                     action).fork();
            }
            for (Node<K,V> p; (p = advance()) != null; )
                action.accept(p.key, p.val);
            propagateCompletion();
        }
    }
}

// forEachEntry
static final class ForEachEntryTask<K,V>
    extends BulkTask<K,V,Void> {
    final Consumer<? super Entry<K,V>> action;
    ForEachEntryTask
        (BulkTask<K,V,?> p, int b, int i, int f, Node<K,V>[] t,
         Consumer<? super Entry<K,V>> action) {
        super(p, b, i, f, t);
        this.action = action;
    }
    public final void compute() {
        final Consumer<? super Entry<K,V>> action;
        if ((action = this.action) != null) {
            for (int i = baseIndex, f, h; batch > 0 &&
                     (h = ((f = baseLimit) + i) >>> 1) > i;) {
                addToPendingCount(1);
                new ForEachEntryTask<K,V>
                    (this, batch >>>= 1, baseLimit = h, f, tab,
                     action).fork();
            }
            for (Node<K,V> p; (p = advance()) != null; )
                action.accept(p);
            propagateCompletion();
        }
    }
}
```

*Somehow like the two methods to set size of Component: `setSize(Dimension)` and `setSize(int, int)`*

Comment: Thanks for your response which explains that even internally they are same; which piques me further as to why two different method then? any particular rationale or just sake of convenience ?

Comment: somehow to help with Lambdas, assume you need to use a method (function) that accepts an Entry - use forEachEntry, Otherwise, if it uses a Key and a Value, use forEach. Kind of hard to say what is just convenience, I mean the whole Java is just for convenience, you could also program directly in Bytecode or even assembler...

Comment: Haha .. I like the way convenience was defined.. :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe it was just a matter of convenience I for instance prefer to have the key an the value already in the parameters intead of having to call getKey()/getValue() all the time. In fact I don't even use/care with forEach functions, once you become more seasoned in functional programming you will learn this kind of function is by far the least useful of FP, so much that purely functional languages like Haskell doesn't even have them. Everything you expect to do with forEach you can do with map/reduce/collect with the added benefit of no side-effects.

BtW: Posting the link to the Javadoc for convenience.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: Thanks for your response and sharing insight from other FP languages!

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously no functional difference. It's just a multiplicated API for a developers comfort. Usually, you use (k,v) parameters for your actions, but sometimes, you could be manipulating the entry-instances and pushing them to some other API consuming Entry<> objects.
Unfortunatelly, I can not figure out any example, but since Entry is an inner class of a map, it could also access some members of the map, the entry is stored in.